# OpenProcess не возвращает хэндл процесса

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

*OpenProcess* не возвращает хэндл процесса, при этом hwnd и procID не равен NULL.

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "race");
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Game window not found" << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {  
        DWORD procID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
        cout << procID << endl;
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);

        if (procID = NULL) {
            cout << "Cannot obtain process." << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(-1);
        }
        else {


        }
```

Comment: А не с правами напряженка?

Comment: У вас в обработке ошибки ошибка - надо сравнивать `if(NULL == handle)` а не `procID` присваивать. И заодно `GetLastError` дергать.

Comment: ```if (procID = NULL)``` то есть, _procID_ будет _NULL_. И как написал **VTT**  у вас не хэндл процесса сравнивается с NULL, а PID процесса, который вы передаете _OpenProcess_.

Comment: Провел правку. Приложение полностью правильно отрабатывает на всех процессах кроме одного, который нужен. В нём находит hwnd, но handle == NULL